# How to model th data for currency exchange rate table in RDMS

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, rdbms

I am trying to implement database modeling for currency exchange rate table.
My task is to pull currency rate by calling an API every day and store it in RDMS.
For example, the output of the API as follows-

```
     {
       'base_currency':'USD',
       'GBP':'0.74081',
       'EUR':'0.88192',
       ........
     } 

     {
       'base_currency':'EUR',
       'GBP':'0.84',
       'RUB':'82.77',
       ........
     }
```

So, for this I am thinking about storing the data in this way

[image: id]

Is there any better way to model this data?
As this table will be populated everyday with huge data then, can it be a problem in the future?

Comment: That is the proper modeling, just make sure you create a unique index on (exchange_date, from_currency,to_currency). Do not worry about volume, you are not anywhere close to huge. Currently there are about 200 nations (via UN) assuming 1 row from each to each daily that is only about 40K rows a day.  You might want to check for volume after 10years when you approach very large (still not huge). NOTE: Do not use date as a column name as it is a Postgres data type and an SQL Standard reserved word.

Comment: Thanks @Belayer, do you think sharding will be good option if the data volume increase over time?

Comment: Eventually **maybe**, but not now. One of the biggest problems faced by even minimally experienced developers/dbas is just getting used to data columns.  In University (or using tutorials) you have data volumes in the 100's to 1000's of rows. Once you get into a production environment everything looks huge as you are now dealing with millions of rows. But to a modern data base that is not large; 100 Million rows not overly large. With the volumes above you get there in about 7years. So a bigger question is "**How long do you need to keep that data?**"